# How can I create account in android in-built account manager via Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, accountmanager

My app should store accounts via account manager but I can`t find some info or examples how can I do it with Xamarin.Forms

Comment: You have to do it from native project. Use this https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Accounts.AccountManager/

Comment: I started with that, but I didn`t figure out how to do all that it says me. I would like to have a example.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're not using an existing account authenticator (google, microsoft, etc.), you have to create an `AccountAuthenticator` service. Then you can then use `AccountManager` to add and/or authenticate user credentials/tokens.

You'll need to peruse the Android SDK documentation and search tutorials on writing the authenticator.

You won't be doing this "with" Xamarin.Forms. It's entirely Android-specific and will have to live in the platform-specific project, not in your Forms project.

The [AccountManager](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Accounts.AccountManager/) class provides access to a centralized registry of the user's online accounts.

Derive from [AbstractAccountAuthenticator](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Accounts.AbstractAccountAuthenticator/) class for creating AccountAuthenticators. In order to be an authenticator one must extend this class, provider implementations for the abstract methods and write a service that returns the result of `AbstractAccountAuthenticator.IBinder` in the service's `Service.OnBind(Intent)` when invoked with an `intent` with action `AccountManager.ActionAuthenticatorIntent`. This service must specify the following intent filter and metadata tags in its AndroidManifest.xml file

Comment: Maybe you have some examples? Have you do this before?

Comment: Start it and if you are stuck on any specific problem ask.

Comment: You are right about it, but I am pretty new in Xamarin and Android and programming at all. I started it before asked answer and I stuck on CreateAccount method because there is intent and activity and other things these I am not clearly understand. So I searched some examples of implementing account manager with Xamarin and i didn't find one. So I didn't really sure if I can do it with Xamarin. If you 100% know that it can be done than I will try more and more.